# Why is this function React component re-rendering after state change?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have the following code...

```
const Thing = ({...})=> {
    const initialState = {
        foo: ''
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const changeFormvalue = (e) => {
        state.foo = e.target.value;
        setState(state);
    }
    return (
        <input type="text" name ="foo"
               value={state.foo}
               onChange={changeFormvalue} />
    )
}
```

When I run I see it hit the function, and I see it set the value. However, after the setState command, the page does not rerender and the value is not updated.

Why is the page not updating?

Comment: Becasue you're directly mutating state and passing `setState` the same object reference. React will not see the update.

Answer (score 0):

Set the state properly (without mutating it).

See **Refactored code** below and read further on links provided in the question's comments.

```js
const Thing = ({...})=> {
    const initialState = {
        foo: ''
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
    const changeFormvalue = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setState(prev => ({...prev, foo: value, assetName: value}));
    }
    return (
        <input type="text" name ="foo"
               value={state.foo}
               onChange={changeFormvalue} />
    )
}
```

Comment: I would think if we are going to mark as duplicate the original post should be edited to make the question clearer